# How to group in Power BI bar chart?

Tags: powerbi, grouping, data-visualization, bar-chart, powerbi-desktop

I have a table of data in PowerBI.
I am producing a basic bar chart on just one of the fields in the data.
The field only has 3 categories, but two of them need to be grouped together? How do I group the 2/3 data bars together so instead of 3 bars, I have 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the answer [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-grouping-and-binning#:%7E:text=To%20use%20grouping%2C%20select%20two,appears%20in%20the%20Fields%20list.)

You could either CTRL-click on the two column you want to group, and once both are selected, click right and select 'Group'. Otherwise, right-click on the field and you will see the 'group' option which will then lead you to the grouping panel on which you can set your desired grouping options.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.